# require other modules in the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
gem install rubyoverflow
irb
> require 'rubyoverflow'
=> true
```

But:

```
require 'rubyoverflow'
include Rubyoverflow

class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
    def question_by_tag
        ruby_q = Questions.retrieve_by_tag('ruby')
```

Get error:

> LoadError in
>   QuestionsController#question_by_tag no
>   such file to load -- rubyoverflow
>
> Rails.root:
>   D:/artefacts/dev/projects/stack
>
> app/controllers/questions_controller.rb:1:in
>   `'
>
> This error occurred while loading the
>   following files:    rubyoverflow

Is there any special rules to import moduled in the controller?

Comment: which ruby are you using and which rails? if it is a gem it is automatically available in your controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do you use both `require`  and `include`? `include Rubyoverflow` will be enough

**UPD**

For gem you should add it into your `Gemfile` (Rails 3.x) or `config/environment.rb` (Rails 2.x)

```
# Gemfile
gem "rubyoverflow"
# environment.rb
config.gem "rubyoverflow"
```

Then run `bundle` for Rails 3.x and `rake gems:install` for Rails 2.x

Comment: Thanks for Gemfile and bundle.